# Single linked list with more data types inside structure

Tags: c++

I have a single linked list, and functions like `AddNode`, `DeleteNode`, `PrintList` work fine but i want to manipulate a bit with it.

So let's say my structure is:

```
struct node
{
     int data;
     node* next;
     bool used;
}
```

So I want `used` in all nodes to be `true`. But if I would like to delete some nodes, then their `used` should be set to false. So basically "used" means that node is in the list. And If I want to print full list, i need to print only nodes with `true`. There is any way to do that? Or is pointless?

I've tried this, but obviously it says that the variable is out of the scope. So how can i do that?

```
void printList()
{
    curr = head;
    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        if (node->used == true)
        {
            cout << curr->data << " ";
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: `node->` what did you hope this would do? It won't work, because `node` is the name of the class, not an instance thereof, but if you explained what it was meant to do, that would help. Did you just mean `curr->`?

Comment: If you fix your conditional to `if (curr->used == true)` then you need to move `curr = curr->next;` out of your if block otherwise you have an infinite loop at the first false.

Answer (score 0):

You are not testing your current node pointer in the `if`, and you are moving to the next element in the wrong location.

Your code should be:

```
    void printList()
    {
        curr = head;
        while(curr != NULL)
        {

            if (curr->used == true)
            {
                 cout << curr->data << " ";
            }

            curr = curr->next;

        }

    }
```